# Differential Equations, Pursuit curves understanding

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently learning ODE's, using the titular book by Tenenbaum and Pollard. I'm stuck trying to understand an example in CH17 that relates to pursuit curves of moving objects (in a plane). I looked at the existing pursuit curve related answers on Stack Exchange (all of which refer to a dog and rabbit, which is probably a metaphor for my situation), but they don't discuss the specific issue I'm running into and trying to understand. And since I'm studying math and physics in my free time (much to the dismay of my lovely wife) understanding is the key here.

The problem: A jet is following a bomber, both have constant speeds, and we know the starting positions of each. The jet always points its nose at the bomber, whereas the bomber never changes direction. I want to find a curve for the path of the jet (for research purposes of course). Brown University seems to host a copy of the book [here](https://www.math.brown.edu/~mgulian/morris-tenenbaum-harry-pollard-ordinary-differential-equations-copy.pdf), and the problem and diagram are on page 178 (same as my physical copy), but I'll paraphrase just in case Brown is just telling copyright law who's in charge.

I didn't understand their choice for theta in the example (it was between Vbx and J-B in my diagram below), so instead I decided to use the dot product to find the angle. Here's the diagram I based everything on:

[Super high quality diagram of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzy9Z.jpg)

And just now while typing this up (don't do math at midnight) I realized I could skip the dot product and a bunch of simplifications. So ditching it we have:
$$
\\ \cos(\theta) = \frac{B_x - J_x}{h}
\\ \sin(\theta) = \frac{J_y - B_y}{h}
$$

The hypotenuse $h$ is just going to cancel out on us anyways, so it doesn't deserve to be written out.

We're looking for a curve $y=f(x)$ for the jet, where $x=J_x, y=J_y$, and $dy/dx$ is all we're missing for our ODE, so:
$$
\\ \frac{dx}{dt} = S_jcos\theta = \frac{S_j(B_x - J_x)}{h}
\\ \frac{dy}{dt} = S_jsin\theta = \frac{S_j(J_y - B_y)}{h}
\\ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{J_y - B_y}{B_x - J_x} = \frac{y - B_y}{B_x - x}
$$

Which is not even remotely a surprise since that's basically rise over run, but like I said, it's late, and context is required for empathy, so let's keep going.

The trouble is that $B_y = B_y(0) + V_{by}t$ and $B_x = B_x(0) + V_{bx}t$ are functions of $t$, and thus are not constant in our equation. $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y - B_y(0) - B_{by}t}{B_x(0) + V_{bx}t - x}$ seems like it's a solvable partial differential equation, but this is an ODE class, and you ODE an ODE class.

The dog and rabbit questions lead me to believe I just need to find $t$ as a function of $x$ and $y$. But I can't seem to find anything to use for such that doesn't result in another function of $x$, $y$, and $t$. A couple of the dog and rabbit solutions solved the curve length as a function of $t$ and $dy/dx$ and used that, but that results in a second order ODE which we haven't covered yet (and I want to avoid for the same reason as avoiding PDEs for now, namely that I want to solve this with just the tools we've been provided so far).

Tenenbaum's solution is not helpful, since it just refers to a previous problem at this step. However, in the referred problem theta is a function of $x$ and $y$ only, whereas in this problem theta is a function of $x$, $y$, $B_y$, and $B_x$, the latter two of which are functions of t as described. Tenenbaum's solution also has this issue, which makes me suspect that "[h]ence it can be solved by the method suggested there" is a lie far more serious than cake.

Thank you for your time and electrons.